# Prémices / Prémisses

Tags: orthographe, homonymes

Quelle est la différence entre *Prémices* et *Prémisses*?

Selon l'*OQLF*,

> *Prémices* désigne le début, le commencement de quelque chose.
>
> Prémisse désigne une proposition faite au début d’un exposé, dont on déduira des conséquences ou des conclusions.

Mais, par exemple, si l'on parle des débuts de l'économie, parle-t-on des prémices ou des prémisses de l'économie ?

Comment: Il me semble que tu réponds toi-même à ta question.

Comment: *Prémisse* est surtout employé en logique. Si on tape "prémisses de l'économie" dans google il retourne automatiquement les occurrences de "prémices de l'économie".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pour le début de l'économie, c'est *prémices*. Le terme *prémisse* appartient au vocabulaire de la logique. Une prémisse est une proposition qui va être utilisée pour la conclusion d'un syllogisme. Exemple de syllogisme :

> Tous les chats sont gris. (prémisse 1)
>   Minou est un chat. (prémisse 2)
>   Donc, Minou est gris. (conclusion du syllogisme)